# How to go through the OutputFormat.RecordWriter write(key,value) twice in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a situation where I need to go through the key/value pairs of my OutputFormat twice. In essence:

```
 OutputFormat.getRecordWriter() // returns RecordWriteType1
 ... and when all those are complete across all machines
 OutputFormat.getRecordWriter() // return RecordWriterType2
```

The  typing of both RecordWriterType1/2 are the same. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,
Marko.

Comment: Do you mean iterating over the reducer key/values again? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean. I would like it I can go through my key/values twice in the same "OutputFormat-run."

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot simply run over the reducer data twice.

You do have some options to possibly work around:

- Use an identity reducer to output the sorted data to HDFS, then run two jobs over the data with identity mappers - wasteful but simple if you don't have that much data
- As above, but you could use map only jobs and the key comparator to emulate the reducer function as you know the input is already sorted (you'll need to make sure the split size is set sufficiently large to ensure all data from the first reducer output file is processed in a single mapper and not split over 2+ mapper instances
- You could write the reducer key/values to local disk in your reducer, and then in the clean up method of the reducer, opening the local file up and process as detailed in the second option (using the group comparator to detemine key boundary).
- If you dig through the source for ReduceTask, you may even be able to 'abuse' the merged sorted segments on local disk and run over the data again, but this option is pure unadulterated hackery...